# Schema.org type for list of resources or downloads

Tags: schema.org

What schema would be most appropriate for a resource library of downloadable assets?

I can't seem to find anything on schema.org that does well outside of maybe recorded events.

Example resource

- Whitepaper, Date, Description, Link
- Webinar, Date, Presenter, Description, Link

For the past webinars, I could probably use Creative Work type. For other documents I'm really not sure.

Comment: 1) Can you provide an example of the data? 2) Did you find any close/similar types that aren’t appropriate? if yes, please list them.

Comment: Just some thoughts: For the whitepaper you could use something like [Book](http://schema.org/Book) or [Article](http://schema.org/Article). If the webinar is taking place only at a specific date/time you could use eg [EducationEvent](http://schema.org/EducationEvent). If it is a repeating series you could use [Course](http://schema.org/Course). If it is like a book permanent available you could use something like [HowTo](http://schema.org/HowTo)